# Customize the layout of content query web part

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 std on-premise environment and trying to build a product catalog page. All I need to do is show up the products' picture and attributes on a page. I added a content query webpart on the page. The products are listed but I fail to show the thumbnail of products. Is it feasible to show the thumbnail?

I followed Microsoft's guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms497457(v=office.14).aspx for SP2010. But it doesn't work on my SP2013 environment. By import a customed webpart and added to page, the outcome is exactly same as before change.

Comment: As far as I know it is absolutely feasible. At all products' related info are stored in lists. And in these will have info regarding product including its image url. You can use that column in ItemStyle.xsl to create new style with imageurl column

Answer (score 0):

Edit the webpart properties and set item style as "Image on left". Now there will be three text box values we should fill in

1. Image
2. Title
3. Description

In the Image field, put the field which holds the image URL. The fields internal name should be entered.

In the Title field, put the field which holds the title. In your case product attributes. The fields internal name should be entered.

You can ignore the Description field or you can enter another relevant field name you want to display.

**[How to find the field internal name](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)**

- Open list setting page and hover mouse over the field name. Examine the URL and take the value of query string "Field"